# Retry behavior for celery tasks within a chunk

Tags: python, celery

I have a question about retrying celery tasks within a [chunk](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#chunks). My python version is `2.7.9`, and my celery version is `3.1.18`

When an individual task inside a chunk fails, it doesn't seem to be retried, and instead the whole chunk fails together.

First, the task that will fail sometimes:

```py
@app.task(bind=True, default_retry_delay=30, max_retries=5)
def sometimes_add(self, x, y):
    try:
        if random.randint(0, 10) < 8:
            return x + y
        else:
            raise Exception("I'm failing!")
    except Exception as e:
        raise self.sometimes_add.retry(exc=e)
```

And the task called 100 times, and chunked into 5 pieces and therefore 20 tasks:

```
sometimes_add.chunks(zip(range(100), range(100)), 5).apply_async()
```

I would expect the failed task within the chunk to be retried once it has failed, but instead no tasks seem to be retried at all, and the whole chunk of 5 tasks fails as a unit.

I'm very new to Celery, so it definitely could be that I am missing something rather fundamental to the best way to use chunking of tasks. If so I'd appreciate any feedback. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a results backend set up? From the [docs](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#chord-important-notes):

> Tasks used within a chord must not ignore their results. In practice this means that you must enable a CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND in order to use chords. Additionally, if CELERY_IGNORE_RESULT is set to True in your configuration, be sure that the individual tasks to be used within the chord are defined with ignore_result=False. This applies to both Task subclasses and decorated tasks.

Comment: Ah, thanks for your comment! I do indeed have a results backend setup (amqp). Also, it looks like this particular part from the docs is referring to a chord, not to chunks. Are they somehow related?

Answer (score -2):

Looks like there is a syntactical error here:

`sometimes_add.chunks(zip(range(100), range(100)), 5).apply_async()`

You are closing the `zip()` function before adding the third parameter -- the 5. I think it should look like this:

`sometimes_add.chunks(zip(range(100), range(100), 5)).apply_async()`

Comment: No the chunk function takes 2 parameters, an iterable of 'work' and the number of chunks to divide it into.

Comment: The example here seems to disagree... http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#chunks

Comment: You are correct that 2 of the examples there disagree, but I think they are typos. The documentation for `chunks` says the signature is (it, n): http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.task.html#celery.app.task.Task.chunks . Maybe one of us should file an issue with celery to fix the docs?

Comment: To generate this example, I simply replaced the add task with the sometimes_add task, taken directly [from the docs on celery](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#chunks). It seems to run just fine locally - some of the chunks are successful. I was mainly just curious about how to retry tasks that are chunked.  Thanks for the comment!