# How to retry failed tasks in celery chunks or celery starmap

Tags: python, django, celery

I would like to know how to configure these tasks correctly so that the failed tasks can be retried. One thing I have noted is if one of the tasks in the chunk fails, the whole chunk (I assume executed by celery.starmap) fails

Here are some related questions I have checked:

-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30653216/retry-behavior-for-celery-tasks-within-a-chunk

-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65217268/continue-when-task-in-celery-chunks-fails

```
@celery_app.task
def get_item_asteroids_callback(parent_item_id):
    pass


@celery_app.task(
    ignore_result=False,
    autoretry_for=(requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout, TimeoutError, urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError, InterfaceError),
    retry_kwargs={'max_retries': 3},
    retry_backoff=True
)
def get_item_asteroid(work_id):
    """
    Does some stuff that can raise some exceptions.
    """
    raise requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout('Test Exception')


@celery_app.task(ignore_result=False)
def get_item_asteroids(parent_item_id):
    item_ids = [1,2,3.......]
    item_ids = [(item_id,) for item_id in item_ids]
    chunk_size = min(len(item_ids), 128)
    tasks = [get_item_asteroid.chunks(item_ids, chunk_size).group()]
    chord(tasks)(get_item_asteroids_callback.si(parent_item_id))
```

None of the failed tasks is retried (The Retried count is 0)
[image]

[image]